# WPF / C# Changing all comboboxes in selected row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to fill all comboboxes in the selectedRows when I change the selectedindex of a combobox.
I have declared the following combobox:

## XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150" Header="Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Height="22"  IsEditable="True" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" ItemsSource="{StaticResource NameList}" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" x:Name="PF_PRT_NAME" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ComponentInfo.selectedName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

now, if I change the selected index from a combobox, all comboboxes in the selected rows should get the same Selectedindex.

## CODE BEHIND:

**Fill DataGrid**

```
public NewComponents()
        {
            List<ComponentInfo> ticketInfos = new List<ComponentInfo>();
            if (GlobalProperties.IvExe.ActiveEditDocument != null && GlobalProperties.IvExe.ActiveEditDocument.DocumentType == DocumentTypeEnum.kAssemblyDocumentObject)
            {
                foreach (Inventor.Document oDoc in GlobalProperties.IvExe.ActiveEditDocument.AllReferencedDocuments)
                {
                    PropertySet propSet = oDoc.PropertySets[3];
                    int partnumber = 0;
                    if (!(int.TryParse(propSet["part number"].Value, out partnumber)))
                    {
                        ComponentInfo componentInfo = new ComponentInfo() {fileName=oDoc.DisplayName};
                        ticketInfos.Add(componentInfo); 
                    }
                }
            }
            InitializeComponent();
            dataView.ItemsSource = ticketInfos;
        }
```

**Custom Objects**

```
    public class ComponentInfo 
    {
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public string selectedName { get; set; }
    }


    public class NameList : List<string>
    {
        public NameList()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GlobalProperties.lists["PF_PRT_NAME"].Count; i++)
            {
                this.Add(GlobalProperties.lists["PF_PRT_NAME"][i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Selection Changed Event:**

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox2 = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;

            if (sender is System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox && comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                string selectedValue = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

                foreach (var selectedItem in dataView.SelectedItems)
                {
                    ComponentInfo selectedComponent = selectedItem as ComponentInfo;
                    if (selectedComponent != null)
                    {
                        selectedComponent.selectedName = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

                        DataGridRow row = GetSelectedRow(dataView, selectedComponent);
                        Console.WriteLine(row.GetIndex());
                        selectedComponent.selectedName = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot!
Steve

[DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zybIz.png)

here all selectedRows are to be filled with the value test

Comment: Have you tried MVVM? It will a lot easier of you use mvvm, specifically using Community Toolkit.

Comment: @bryanjez i'll have a look, thank you!